# How to make Envelope graph

Tags: graph

How can I create a graph like shown in the Figure attached. I cant figure out a way of doing the graph called Envelope in [image]the image, either Matlab or origin.

Comment: and what is the correct name for this Envelope type of graph? I searched for it but I cant find the similar one at all.

Comment: You must be aware that the image could have been "post-processed". First, use some tool to draw min, max and average, then use MS Paint to fill the resulting areas.

Comment: Just wanted to confirm if this can be done directly without post-processing in matlab or anyother software.

Comment: I am not aware of such tool. However, you should be able to trick Excel to do somber omg similar, once you have the data for min, max and average. Use normal line for average, and stacked bales for min and max